# What is the role of quadratic_error variable in Google's PageRank algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, pagerank, quadratic

There's an implementation of Googles' PageRank on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank):

```
% Parameter M adjacency matrix where M_i,j represents the link from 'j' to 'i', such that for all 'j' sum(i, M_i,j) = 1
% Parameter d damping factor
% Parameter v_quadratic_error quadratic error for v
% Return v, a vector of ranks such that v_i is the i-th rank from [0, 1]

function [v] = rank(M, d, v_quadratic_error)

N = size(M, 2); % N is equal to half the size of M
v = rand(N, 1);
v = v ./ norm(v, 2);
last_v = ones(N, 1) * inf;
M_hat = (d .* M) + (((1 - d) / N) .* ones(N, N));

while(norm(v - last_v, 2) > v_quadratic_error)
        last_v = v;
        v = M_hat * v;
        v = v ./ norm(v, 2);
end

endfunction
```

I can' figure out what's quadratic_error for. It's not described on wikipedia nor in the article's algorithm specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a convergence test. The `while` loop ends when the L<sub>2</sub> difference between `v` and `last_v` does not exceed the value of `v_quadratic_error`.

Here's a bit more explanation. First, note that `M_hat` is a matrix and `v` is a vector. The `while` loop replaces `v` with the product `M_hat * v` (normalized to be a unit vector). The loop ends when the change in `v` due to one iteration is small enough. That's what "convergence" means in this context.

This appears to be the standard [power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) loop for finding the eigenvector corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue of a matrix (in this case of `M_hat`). Without knowing more about the overall algorithm (which I'm not going to research), I can't say why this calculation is useful.

Comment: Can you explain it more in detail? What's convergence in this context?

Comment: @Tool - I added an explanation to my answer.